# Alternative pump for Nemo airbeam tent

Tags: tents

I have a Nemo Morpho tent with inflatable airbeams and have somehow managed to lose the included foot pump. I've found a few US retailers with a replacement pump in stock (called 'Nemoid Foot Pump'), but living in Germany and needing the pump in a three weeks time, I am not sure if delivery and customs clearance will complete in time.

**Update July 2018** - The question is still current, as I have not yet managed to find a replacement pump for the tent. The situation is however slightly different. Nemo, the manufacturer, seems not to produce the tent anymore and does not offer replacement parts anymore. I am right now not able to find any dealer world wide, which sells a replacement pump. If anyone knows the valve connector and can recommend a pump from a different manufacturer or knows where to get an original Nemo pump, I would still very much apprechiate an answer to this question.

As far as I can tell, the connector between the pump tube and the airbeam valve is a proprietary "click & close" system from Nemo.

Can anyone tell if they recognize the connector and perhaps suggest a pump from another manufacturer suitable for connecting to the Nemo tents?

Alternatively: There are several European dealers selling the tents or other products from Nemo, but noone seem to stock spare parts. If someone could suggest a European dealer able to send me the pump within a reasonable time, that would also solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Nemo says their beams are 7-9 PSI

http://shield.nemoequipment.com/explore/technology/airsupported-technology/

Should be very easy to improvise a connection that will not leak.  Get any pump rated for that pressure (it will be for a thing like an inflatable boat not a bicycle) which is of a size you can stand to carry, and find someone with a workshop in the garage or basement.  My guess is with some off the shelf pump and maybe o-rings from a faucet you’ll be good to go.

Further note regarding pumps:
Keep in mind that this kind of inflatable has two phases of inflation:  phase one where the air goes in without any resistance (0 psi over atmospheric pressure) then phase two where it’s almost full and you need to force the last bit in (to 7-9 psi over atmospheric pressure).  It’s this last phase where it gets structural strength.
During phase one you want rapid airflow, pressure can be very low, virtually anything will work.  Your lungs could do it but then you introduce moisture and bacteria so best avoided.  A bellows, a bag that you squeeze would work.  Whatever.
During phase two you need enough pressure but not too much.  You could use eveb a tiny bike pump or even squeeze bulb for this last little bit if you were patient and careful not to overpressure.  If you know how the inflatable beam is supposed to feel you could just rely on squeezing it to keep from overpressuring.

Comment: Since I used to use the tent when bicycling, glueing a bicycle tube valve onto/into the air beams may actually be quite a good idea. The whole point with the tent is to keep the pack volume as small as possible, so it would defeat the entire purpose to have to bring a different, larger pump to inflate it. A small bicycle pump is usually part of my stuff anyway and might work.

Comment: Yeah the challenge will be the first part where you have to get the tube 99% full, moving all that air via the bike valve will be painfully slow..I think you’re onto something w the pump reuse but instead of gluing the valve straight to the tent what if you glue to a rubber stopper that you can remove entirely for rapid-inflating via a squeeze bag then inserting/topping off with the pump?

Comment: A presta valve will be much better than a schraeder I think as far as airflow at low pressure

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gKu2TXiGMjA DIY air mattress inflators are a YouTube genre apparently

Comment: By the way if you post some pix of the valve (any snapshots very useful, but ideally including one straight on pointing at the valve opening, zoomed or cropped from a distance to eliminate lens distortion, with an object of known size like a ruler or coin beside it) I’m happy to suggest opportunities/issues.  I’m fascinated by inflatable gear but have never owned an inflatable tent.

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is old but I pulled my Nemo Morpho tent out for the first time in ten years and one of the beams ("bladders") looses air now and doesn't stay inflated more than five minutes. Unfortunately Nemo no longer makes these bladders. However, in my search I found that the inflator connector (which one connects to the bladder) is engraved with "CPC". There is a connector company still around called CPC, but it seems that they make more medical grade connectors (https://www.cpcworldwide.com/General-Purpose/Products), although they do look similar to the one on the end of the included pump. If you are missing a pump you might contact them to see if they could send you the connector, and you may then be able to use it to connect something like a hand pump or similar foot pump.

Comment: Thank you for picking up this question after 8 years :-) I have actually since then found the pump and I can use the tent again. If one of your beams is leaking, I would very much assume that you can fix it with a bike tube patch.